# How to Find an Element to Click on Instagram Unfollow Button

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

I am making an Instagram bot using selenium and python. I am trying to implement a function which allows a certain amount of followers to be unfollowed. The code navigates to the unfollow screen which has many buttons that say unfollow. The buttons are hard to find with selenium though. If the find_element_by_tag('button') function is used only 3 buttons are found. The button html is:

```
<button class="_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy   _8A5w5    " type="button">Following</button>
```

For some reason, I cannot get selenium to select the element. Are there any ways someone can see how to click it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the active element and then clicking on the following

driver. switchTo() . activeElement() ;

And then try the xpath that you tried. This should work

Answer (score 0):

Copy the xpath of the button tag and create reference and use for loop to iterate from one unfollow button onto the next, see my github repository

https://github.com/asadamatic/Unfollow-All-On-Instagram/blob/master/unfollowAll.py